# How to fix https not work htaccess in hotlink protection

Tags: .htaccess

How to fix https not work htaccess in hotlink protection

i using htaccess in hotlink protection. Its work on normal http

and not work in https how to rewrite ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?XXX.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?XXX.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*google.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*iphone.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*iPad.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*Android.* [NC]
RewriteRule \.(flv|mp4|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there's security profiles that don't send referers when you're navigating a site using HTTPS. You could try just ignoring the hotlink protection in this case:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?XXX.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?XXX.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?XXX.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?XXX.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*google.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*iphone.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*iPad.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !.*Android.* [NC]
RewriteRule \.(flv|mp4|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```